calling select(matches()) inside a function
I have a large df where I want to select all columns that reference a particular year
cl_2019 <- c(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
X2019_foo <-c("apple", "grape", "lemon", "blueberry", "pluot", "lime", "pear", "pluot")
cl_2018 <-c(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14)
X2018_foo <-c("kiwi", "grape", "pluot", "watermelon", "plum", "pear", "pear", "strawberry")
test_dat <- data.frame(cl_2019, X2019_foo, cl_2018, X2018_foo)

this works
test <- test_dat %>% 
  select(matches("2019"))

this doesn't, and raises an error
get_year <- function (df, year){
  
  df2 <- df %>% 
    select(matches({{"year"}}))
}

test3 <- get_year(test_dat,2019)

Error in FUN():
! arg must be a symbol
Clearly I've got the syntax wrong in my function, but I'm not sure where and would appreciate advice. Thanks.

Instead of ”year“, use paste(year).

@deschen You didn't explain why that worked. It cannot be the case that the base function paste is being used since it would not retrun a symbol. (I have a theory.) This is also a duplicate of a question that was asked and answered a couple of days ago but not with this particular answer.

One of the error messages says match must be a character vector of non empty strings., so select(matches(year)) and calling it with get_year(test_dat, "2019") should be the most straightforward way.

@IRTFM paste is working because matchesrequires a character string und using paste will turn the input into one. @Andre Wildberg, despite your comment showing an obvious workaround, there might be use cases where passing the original value instead of the character representation might be preferable.
